# Find the altitude of a point

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a polygon layer and I want to know the altitude of the centroids. I guess I have to find on the internet (how?) a layer that contains data about the territory's height (in this case Italy in particular Toscana and Liguria) and to find a way to correlate it with my layer (using Python is better). Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
vlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Centroids')[0]
rlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Elevation')[0]
params = {'INPUT_VECTOR': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(vlayer.id(), True), 
          'INPUT_RASTER': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(rlayer.id(), True), 
          'COLUMN_PREFIX' : 'Altitude',
          'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}

newLayer = processing.run("qgis:rastersampling", params)
layerOutput = newLayer['OUTPUT']
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerOutput)
```

I tried in this way, but there's something wrong. This is the error message: Could not load source layer for INPUT: no value specified for parameter

Comment: You will need a Digital Elevation Model (DEM). You can download tiles for your area of interest here (90m): https://dwtkns.com/srtm/  or here (30m): https://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/. Create centroids and run 'Sample raster values' algorithm, then join elevation attribute back to polygon layer. If you want a Python solution you should try to make a code attempt.

Comment: Thanks both. I did it, now I'm trying to do the same task using python. The only way I could think is using processing.run algorithm ("qgis:rastersampling") but i'm not sure how to set params and I can't find any example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
vlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('New scratch layer')[0]
rlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('nh_62_3')[0]

centroids = [g.geometry().centroid() for g in vlayer.getFeatures()]

#Create a point layer from polygon centroids
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs={}&index=yes".format(vlayer.crs().authid()), "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()
for centroid in centroids:
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(centroid)
    provider.addFeature(f)

#Set z from raster
pointz = processing.run("native:setzfromraster", 
    {'INPUT':vl,
    'RASTER':rlayer.source(),'BAND':1,'NODATA':0,'SCALE':1,
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

#Extract z value
pointz2 = processing.run("native:extractzvalues", 
    {'INPUT':pointz,'SUMMARIES':[0],'COLUMN_PREFIX':'z_',
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(pointz2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works. Is there a way to maintain in the new layer `pointz2` the attributes of the first vector layer?

Comment: Spatial join / join attributes by location. Or start with centroid that has attributes.